# Изменение цвета текста кнопки из кода

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Столкнулся с такой проблемой на unity - не могу изменить цвет текста на кнопке при наведении. Это UI элемент.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {

    [SerializeField] private Color highlighted;
    [SerializeField] private Color normal;

    void Start () {
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = normal;
    }


    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData){
        Debug.LogError("KYPCOP HABEDEH");
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = highlighted;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData){
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = highlighted;
    }
}
```

При старте цвет меняется, а при наведении нет. Сначала думал, что не срабатывает наведение и поставил вывод в консоль сообщения - все срабатывает. Не понятно, неужели из под кода цвет текста уже нельзя менять? Видел вариант с помощью анимации, он работает, но это немного не мой вариант, т.к. если я поставлю игру на паузу, то анимация перехода цветов работать не будет. Как быть?

Comment: Я повесил твой скрипт на кнопку, переменные Color сделал public, в инспекторе выбрал цвет (не забудь про альфа канал). И все работает.

Comment: Понял, что это работает, если у кнопки параметр Transition выставлен в Animation. В остальных случаях цвет не меняется. Но это не то, что хотелось видеть, ведь если я поставлю Time.timeScale = 0(пауза игры), то цвет меняться не будет. Хочется сделать паузу игры, где появляется меню паузы, а на фоне остановленная игра. Как тогда быть?

Comment: В общем, наверное буду искать всех персонажей в сцене и отключать им скрипты и анимации при паузе. Как-то так что ли...

Comment: У меня меняется и при Transition "None" на кнопке, а так же при "Time.timeScale = 0". Попробуй сделать новую сцену для теста, там ничего кроме кнопки, Canvas и EventSystem, и там проверь.

Comment: Действительно, в отдельной сцене работает, сделал главное меню, там все то же самое, по тому же принципу, но цвет меняется. Как так? В сцене с игрой, меню паузы почему-то так не работает... Из-за чего тогда такое может быть?

Comment: Решил вроде бы проблему, создал кнопку заново, навесил скрипт, и все работает. Сравнил рабочую с нерабочей - все одинаково. Не понятно, что ей нужно... Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы наверно ошиблись

```
public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData){
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = highlighted;
    }
```

а нужно

```
public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData){
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color = normal;
    }
```

Comment: Да здесь есть ошибка, не уследил. У меня в коде ее не было, я потом ее исправил, после того как разместил вопрос. Но все равно не работало. У меня было две кнопки с этими симптомами, одну я удалил и забыл, потом наткнулся на вторую. У второй(не рабочей) был добавлен аниматор, после удаления этого компонента скрипт заработал как положено. Как-то так.

Comment: пометьте как правельный ответ пожалуйста =)